# Stop an element from moving on window resize

Tags: css

I am currently making the footer of my project, and somehow every element I code seems to move every time I (or the user) resizes the window.

I have tried -

1. `margin: 0 auto;`
2. `position: relative;  float: left;`

**EDIT**:

Code:

```
    .pdiv{
    /* div might be helpful? */
}

.footer {
    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
}
```

Comment: What's about use code snipped and add full code correctly to your question? If not then set the width and height "stiff".

Comment: @MateoProgramistaZaDyche Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by 'stiff'? thanks for the help!

Comment: @MateoProgramistaZaDyche I also edited my post for the code if you want to refer

Comment: I mean that that you need to set the width and height. If you will not do that the size of the element (like div) will depend on that what you have inside this element. Another thing is that is hard to understand what you want to do if you didn't show the whole snipped or even part of it to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use flexbox in your footer,

```
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;   // or flex-end, flex-start of your choice how you want them to look
  align-items: center; // or same as above
}
```

Comment: thanks! The key is that I need `display: flex;`!

Answer (score -1):

Make yourself a favor and please use flexbox instead of floats, please, floats are not meant to do layout, this is more historical as before flexbox, there was no "universal" nor "adapted" way to compose clear layouts (dont start me on table's, plz).

This may help you:

- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/07/enhancing-css-layout-floats-flexbox-grid/ (Float to Flexbox migration)
- https://flexboxfroggy.com - A game to learn Flexbox